# Differences between servers regarding the UTF-8 BOM

Tags: php, apache, csv, character-encoding, byte-order-mark

I have my application developed on a WAMP installation with PHP 5.4, fully configured with UTF-8.

Now I need to generate a .csv files. The encoding must be ISO-8859-1 for requirements beyond my control.

They are very small tables and I edit in a string with

> iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1 // TRANSLIT", $each_data);

Then I download the file with this:

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=ISO-8859-1');
header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="'.$filename.'";');
echo $string_with_all_data;
exit(0);
```

Well, in my development server there is no problem, the file is generated as need. But in production server, the generated .csv includes UTF-8 BOM at the beginning.

In theory both servers are identical. However, one generates a csv with the infamous 3 characters at the begin (**ï»¿**) and the other not. Both csv are correctly encoded in ISO-8859-1.

I've tried a thousand ways, but always the results are different in both files generated. (fputcsv, ob_start(), Content-Type: bla-bla, etc, etc...)

I suposse there must be some difference in php or apache configuration that changes the output, but I could not find it.

Comment: BOM is never "generated" by PHP. If it's there in the script's output, that's because the script file itself has BOM which gets sent to the output because it precedes the opening `<?php` tag. While there might be some more or less hacky ways to filter it out automatically, your best bet is never to encode your scripts with BOM in the first place.

Comment: @lafor: In practice what should I do?